# A Question about Obtaining a Label from a Datatable

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I am storing and removing labels with a data table, so I can add/remvove the labels that correspond to the state of checklist items. I am able successfully store and use a checklist within one of the columns (I am only using the checklist and an index for row selection. This works fine, however I think the checklist selection is only being done by converting some of the identifier into a string), but I can not figure out how to pull the label and remove it from the form. My (compressed) attempt as follow results in null being pulled from where a label should be.

```
myTable.Rows.Add(myCheckList, checklistIndex, myLabel);

...

DataRow[] myRows = myTable.Select(string.Format("Checklist = '{0}' AND Index = '{1}'", myCheckList, checklistIndex));
DataRow removeRow = myRows[0];
Label removeLabel = removeRow[2] as Label;
// removeLabel.Visible = false; this does not work and returns null
Controls.Remove(removeLabel);
```

I know I am getting the correct row because I have a data view grid linked to my data table. The rows are added and removed (not shown in code sample) as expected, but my label keeps coming back as null.

How can I access this label and remove it? Am I unable to access a label this way?

Comment: It's null because `removeRow[2]` is not a `Label` control.

Comment: I'm not sure what the label represents in this context, is the label part of the datatable or is it a single, standalone label?

Comment: myLabel is a standalone label that is made during run-time. I did confirm that I can remove the label when it is searched by name, but maybe the table will not allow me to actually store form components? I should also clarify that the label is created and added to the form before I store it in the data table.

Comment: I believe I need to just switched to using the label names. It seems the label is converted from a control to a string when stored. Good to know for the future.

Comment: It's actually converted to an object, but I can cast the object to a string and use that to get my label. Got it working now. Thanks for the comments to get the squirrels running on their wheels.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to store and obtain a label control to and from a data table. It is converted to an object and is not considered a Label anymore.

The answer is to store label names instead.